# На новом пк установил IDEA и встретил ошибки в pom.xml файле

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

В него я вставил зависимости из прошлого проекта. Изначально в IDEA у меня не появилось окно автоимпорта и я включил его в настройках, после этого зависимости перестали подсвечиваться, все кроме одной:

> spring-boot-maven-plugin

В сообщение об ошибке написано:

> invalid packaging for parent pom must be pom but is jar  и plugin
> org.springframework.boot spring-boot-maven-plugin not found.

И еще у меня подсвечивается project в самом начале. При попытке поднять приложение оно падает вот что дает стректейс:

> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to
> start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing
> ServletWebServerFactory bean.
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:206)
> ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:180)
> ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:154)
> ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
> ... 8 common frames omitted

вот зависимости:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.javastart</groupId>
<artifactId>hello-string</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<build>
    <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>




<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


</project>
```

Comment: Сборка из командной строки работает?

Comment: В примере в [документации](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) используется `<relativePath/>` в элементе `<parent>`. Пробовали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В pom.xml неверно поставлен parent, а надо вот так

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

и зависимости

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```